# pandas / dask calculate percentages for multiple columns - column-parallel operation

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-processing, dask

When I have a data frame in pandas like:

```
raw_data = {
        'subject_id': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
        'name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
        'nationality': ['DE', 'AUT', 'US', 'US', 'US'],
        'alotdifferent': ['x', 'y', 'z', 'x', 'a'],
        'target': [0,0,0,1,1],
        'age_group' : [1, 2, 1, 3, 1]}
df_a = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['subject_id', 'name', 'nationality', 'alotdifferent','target','age_group'])
df_a.nationality = df_a.nationality.astype('category')
df_a.alotdifferent = df_a.alotdifferent.astype('category')
df_a.name = df_a.name.astype('category')
```

Currently, I use:

```
FACTOR_FIELDS = df_a.select_dtypes(include=['category']).columns
columnsToDrop = ['alotdifferent']
columnsToBias_keep = FACTOR_FIELDS[~FACTOR_FIELDS.isin(columnsToDrop)]
target = 'target'

def quotients_slow(df_a):
    # parallelism = 8
    # original = dd.from_pandas(df.copy())
    original = df_a.copy()
    output_df = original
    ratio_weights = {}

    for colname in columnsToBias_keep.union(columnsToDrop):
        # group only a single time
        grouped = original.groupby([colname, target]).size() 
        # calculate first ratio
        df = grouped / original[target].sum() 
        nameCol = "pre_" + colname 
        grouped_res = df.reset_index(name=nameCol) 
        grouped_res = grouped_res[grouped_res[target] == 1] 
        grouped_res = grouped_res.drop(target, 1) 
        # todo persist the result in dict for transformer
        result_1 = grouped_res

        # calculate second ratio
        df = (grouped / grouped.groupby(level=0).sum()) 
        nameCol_2 = "pre2_" + colname 
        grouped = df.reset_index(name=nameCol_2) 
        grouped_res = grouped[grouped[target] == 1] 
        grouped_res = grouped_res.drop(target, 1) 
        result_2 = grouped_res 

        # persist the result in dict for transformer
        # this is required to separate fit and transform stage (later on in a sklearn transformer)
        ratio_weights[nameCol] = result_1
        ratio_weights[nameCol_2] = result_2

        # retrieve results
        res_1 = ratio_weights['pre_' + colname]
        res_2 = ratio_weights['pre2_' + colname]
        # merge ratio_weight with original dataframe
        output_df = pd.merge(output_df, res_1, on=colname, how='left') 
        output_df = pd.merge(output_df, res_2, on=colname, how='left') 
        output_df.loc[(output_df[nameCol].isnull()), nameCol] = 0 
        output_df.loc[(output_df[nameCol_2].isnull()), nameCol_2] = 0 

        if colname in columnsToDrop:
            output_df = output_df.drop(colname, 1)

    return output_df


quotients_slow(df_a)
```

to calculate the ratio of each group to `target:1` for each (categorical) column in two ways. As I want to perform the this operation for multiple columns, I  naively iterating all of them. But this operation is very slow. 
Here in the sample: `10 loops, best of 3: 37 ms per loop`. For my real dataset of around 500000 rows and around 100 columns this really takes a while.

Shouldn't it be possible to speed it up (column parallel manner, trivial parallelization) in either dask or pandas? Is there a possibility to implement it more efficiently in plain pandas? Is it possible to reduce the number of passes over the data for computing the quotients?

## edit

when trying to use `dask.delayed` in the for loop to achieve parallelism over the columns, I can't figure out how to *build the graph over the columns*, as I need to call compute to get the tuples.

```
delayed_res_name = delayed(compute_weights)(df_a, 'name')
a,b,c,d = delayed_res_name.compute()
ratio_weights = {}
ratio_weights[c] = a
ratio_weights[d] = b
```

Comment: Maybe a single pass is possible similar to the demo here: https://jcrist.github.io/dask-sklearn-part-3.html

Comment: "The percentages of the `target` column per any other column..."  Your calculation here derives an unusual kind of proportion.  For example, the `name:A`/`target:0` combo occurs in 1 of 5 observations.  But you're dividing `1 occurrence` by  the sum of `1` values in `target`.  Imagine if you had 3 entries of `name:A`/`target:0`, but still only two `1` values in `target`.  Should the `name:A`/`target:0` proportion be 1.5, or 150%?

Comment: You might be right, and I need to think about this, but the main point is I want to *parallelize / efficiently implement such a division* (sort of percentage). And actually, `target:0` is irrelevant. I am only interested in `target:1`, or pointed out differently: the proportion of `target:1/allRecords` per each group per each column. Maybe this is a better formulation.

Comment: In that case, please consider updating the main text of your question with your exact use case. The computation procedure itself may be important in addressing your question about efficiency, as Pandas has built-in optimizations for certain operations and sequences of operations.

Comment: To be clear, if `name:A` occurs 3 times in a dataset with 5 total observations, and `name:A`/`target:1` occurs 1 time, then the desired proportion calculation for the `name:A`/`target:1` grouping should be 0.33?

Comment: Actually, I calculate 2 *percentages/ divisions*: one, exactly as you mentioned, and another one as outlined above. Please find an example which is a bit more involved at the following link: https://github.com/geoHeil/pythonQuestions/blob/master/percentageCodingSpeedup.ipynb

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143574/discussion-between-andrew-reece-and-georg-heiler).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a reasonably fast solution for your first quotient, using Pandas. It assumes you are not interested in computing proportions for `subject_id`. I also added some data to your example to cover more edge cases.

First, generate sample data:

```
raw_data = {
    'subject_id': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6','7'],
    'name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'A','A'],
    'nationality': ['DE', 'AUT', 'US', 'US', 'US', 'DE','DE'],
    'alotdifferent': ['x', 'y', 'z', 'x', 'a','x','z'],
    'target': [0,0,0,1,1,0,1],
    'age_group' : [1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2,1]}

df_a = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['subject_id', 'name', 'nationality', 'alotdifferent','target','age_group'])
```

Now compute proportions and measure speed:

```
def compute_prop(group):
    return group.sum() / float(group.count())

def build_master(df):
    master = df.copy()
    fields = df.drop(['subject_id','target'],1).columns

    for field in fields:
        master = (pd.merge(master, df.groupby(field, as_index=False)
                                     .agg({'target':compute_prop})
                                     .rename(columns={'target':'pre_{}'.format(field)}), 
                           on=field)
             )

    master.sort_values('subject_id')
    return master

%timeit master = build_master(df_a)
10 loops, best of 3: 17.1 ms per loop
```

Output:

```
  subject_id name nationality alotdifferent  target  age_group  pre_name  \
0          1    A          DE             x       0          1  0.333333   
5          2    B         AUT             y       0          2  0.000000   
2          3    C          US             z       0          1  0.000000   
6          4    D          US             x       1          3  1.000000   
3          5    E          US             a       1          1  1.000000   
4          6    A          DE             x       0          2  0.333333   
1          7    A          DE             z       1          1  0.333333   

   pre_nationality  pre_alotdifferent  pre_age_group  
0         0.333333           0.333333            0.5  
5         0.000000           0.000000            0.0  
2         0.666667           0.500000            0.5  
6         0.666667           0.333333            1.0  
3         0.666667           1.000000            0.5  
4         0.333333           0.333333            0.0  
1         0.333333           0.500000            0.5
```

Comment: Is it possible to add the second case as well / to compute both aggregations in a single pass? I think only the following line needs to be added `df = (grouped / grouped.groupby(level=0).sum())` Is it possible to pass a second function to `agg`?

Comment: But I do not really see what is different from my initial solution. There, I already loop over all the fields and aggregate the data. You just combine the steps, i.e the code is a lot cleaner. But could this yield any performance efficiencies? In the end it needs to be a sklearn transformer which stores the *weights* as outlined in the notebook. So the combination of merge and group you use would probably require to be separated.